# Xcode 11 Beta 4 Archive swift errors

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, beta, xcode11

With the latest Xcode 11 I am getting tons of Swift errors when archiving. Building in debug works fine, the issue is only while archiving.

Example error --> *Undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.<...>*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official workaround is to add a custom build setting with the name LD_VERIFY_BITCODE, and set it to NO.

Just remember to remove when issue is resolved!

[image]

Comment: It's in the official release note: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes

Comment: I did this. It still gives me the Swift errors. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: This worked for me, and is the 'official' workaround for the issue. Have you tried deleting your derived data folder, cleaning and re-starting Xcode? Maybe your old build settings are still getting picked up.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Beta 5